# return throw exception in Kotlin

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

I have the following problem, I can't return this exception. It's giving an error 500 and doesn't run this exception.
I wish that when I entered the if it would already return this custom exception.

**KOTLIN**

```
    class CustomExceptionName(message: String) : Exception(message)
     
        @PostMapping
        fun createUsers(@RequestBody user: User): ResponseEntity<User> {
            var pattern = Regex("[^0-9]")
            var emailExist = false
            emailExist = this.userRepository.existsByEmail(user.email)
            if (emailExist) {
              throw CustomExceptionName("email exist")
            }
            user.telephone = pattern.replace(user.telephone, "")
            return ResponseEntity.ok(this.userRepository.save(user))
        }
```

**JAVA**

```java
      public class DomainException extends RuntimeException {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public DomainException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }

        @Override
        public Client create(Client client) {
            boolean clientExists = clientRepository.findByEmail(client.getEmail())
                    .stream()
                    .anyMatch(emailExists -> !emailExists.equals(client));
            boolean cnpjExists = clientRepository.findByCnpj(client.getCnpj())
                    .stream()
                    .anyMatch(emailExists -> !emailExists.equals(client));
            if(clientExists) {
                throw new DomainException("Já existe um cliente cadastrado com esse e-mail");
            }
            if(cnpjExists) {
                throw new DomainException("Já existe um cliente cadastrado com esse cnpj");
            }
            return clientRepository.save(client);
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean it isn't throwing the exception? What makes you think it isn't throwing the exception if `emailExist` is true?

Comment: Exactly, on Postman Only return on Error 500.
There is no custom exception

Comment: And what do you see in the logs of your application?

Comment: response postman "{
    "timestamp": "2021-10-01T14:50:33.918+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "path": "/api/users"
}"

Comment: The error appears on the console. But what I want is that the error returns in the request.
That the error appears in Postman, so when the front requests it has this error message

Comment: You throw the exception and your webserver framework catches this and returns a 500, this is what most frameworks do as it's just plain sensible, the alternative is for the server to crash... If you want to customize the error message in the 500, consult the documentation of the web framework you use for how to do this.

Comment: Stack traces in HTTP responses are never a good idea and you should definitely not do that.

Comment: Then you'd need an exception handler that converts the exception to a response--the exception is being thrown, which is different than not getting the HTTP response you want.

Comment: I believe I didn't explain it in the best way.
I'll show you how I use it in Java.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: if the exception is not caught or handled anywhere, your client will see a 500 Internal Server Error because basically the request fails unexpectedly. If you want to handle the error then you should handle the exception or return the response you want to see. Assuming you're using Spring MVC framework, check this: https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Comment: " Exceptions" are not what gets sent to the client--HTTP responses are returned. If the app has an unhandled/unmapped exception it's going to return whatever it uses as its default exception HTTP response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `RestControllerAdvice` or `ControllerAdvice` like

```
@ControllerAdvice
class ControllerAdviceRequestError : ResponseEntityExceptionHandler() {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = [(CustomExceptionName::class)])
    fun handleCustomExceptionName(ex: CustomExceptionName,request: WebRequest): ResponseEntity<String> {
       
        return ResponseEntity(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, perfect